# Empty listview with retrofit 2.0

Tags: java, android, json, string, listview

I have listview that have to fill from JSON file but until now after running app I see nothing and I don't know if the problem from java codes or JSON file??
also I notice that I can't add file extensions inside @Path ,,

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);





    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    TelService service = retrofit.create(TelService.class);
    final retrofit.Call<List<tel_list>> calls = service.getphones("telephones");
    calls.enqueue(new Callback<List<tel_list>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<tel_list>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

           if (!response.isSuccess()) {
               //TODO
               return;
           }
            List<tel_list> telephones = response.body();

            TelAdapter adapter = new TelAdapter (MainActivity.this, telephones);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}
}
```

TelService.java

```
public interface TelService {
@GET("/alruthea/{getphones_1}.php")
retrofit.Call<List<tel_list>> getphones(@Path("getphones_1")String telephones);


}
```

TelAdapter.java

```
public class TelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<tel_list> {

private Context context;
private List<tel_list> telephones;


public TelAdapter(Context context, List<tel_list> data) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, data);
    telephones = data;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView name = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.names);
    name.setText(telephones.get(position).getName());
    TextView number = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.numbers);
    number.setText(telephones.get(position).getNumber());

    return item;


}
}
```

tel_list.java

```
public class tel_list {

private String name;
private String number;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}
}
```

Comment: Please I need to solution